# ScrollViewer scrollbar always disabled

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to xaml and wpf.
I am trying to insert some user controls into a container from the code-behind.
I have read this blog entry on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2009/06/09/stackpanel-dockpanel-and-scrolling-items.aspx).
I tried all the methods used there and some others but the scroll bar is never enabled.
My current code that I stuck with is this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,12,0,0">
        <ItemsControl Name="captchaControls" Width="339" Height="286">

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Does anyone know why?

EDIT:
Made it work like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,12,0,0" Width="339" Height="286">
        <ItemsControl Name="captchaControls">

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `Width="339" Height="286"` from XAML. It causes ItemsControl to have constant size no matter what is inside it.

BTW. You should probably use `x:Name` instead of `Name`, google for articles explaining why.

Comment: Well, yeah, but for naming purposes you should stick to using x:Name since some objects may not have Name property.

Comment: I don't think much of that, it's as pointless as writing `this.*`, actually even more so as it does not even show a difference between scopes.